# Нужен перевод на странице предлагаемых правок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

Нужен перевод для кнопок выбора режима просмотра правки.

> [image: Страница просмотра предложенной правки]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14868

   > Обработанный результат
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14869

   > Markdown разметка